# obtain certificate from ftps server with explicit SSL/TLS

Tags: ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, ftps

Is there a tool which can obtain a certificate in a form of .cert file form a ftps server with explicit SSL/TLS?

Comment: I believe this question is a bit off topic for SO. It might be more suitable for [superuser](http://superuser.com) or similar. Voting to close.

Comment: I don't prefer close without simple explanation. You can found resolve for this on https://superuser.com/questions/665582/save-certificate-to-use-with-lftp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. It is [FireFTP](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fireftp/) add-on for FireFox which enables FTPS protocol and stores certificate in FireFox default store. Install add-on and just type in address bar ftps://your.site. After that, certs can easily be exported from tools->options->advanced->encryption->vew certs

Comment: This is almost there, except how do I know which one in the view is the cert I need?

Comment: better do it with openssl with -starttls ftp   option